# Multiple Forms to same location in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I broke my form and am trying to make two different pages and finally PUT data to same initial route(ACTION), but I see data from the second page
only:
This is the first part of the form which I broke into the first page, keeping the  action same:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 style="text-align: center">Register Yourself</h1>
        <div style="width: 30%; margin: 25px auto;">
            <form action="/students" method="POST">
                <label>Name:</label> <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
                </div>

                
                </form>
          <a href="/students/p2">Proceed!</a>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the second part of the form which I put in the second page:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 style="text-align: center">Register Yourself</h1>
        <div style="width: 30%; margin: 25px auto;">
            <form action="/students" method="POST">
                 <label for="preference">Choose a catagory:</label>
                    <select name="preference" class="form-control">
                     <option value="Male">Male</option>
                      <option value="Female">Female</option>
                      <option value="Any">Any</option>
                     </select>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ">Submit!</button>
                </div>
                </form>
                
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the route where we are taking data from form and adding to the db and posting finally:

```
router.post("/students",middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    // get data from form and add to students array
    var name       = req.body.name;
    var preference = req.body.preference;
    var author = {
        id: req.user._id,
        username: req.user.username
    }
    var newstudent = {name: name,preference: preference}
    // Create a new student and save to DB
    
    Student.create(newstudent, function(err, newlyCreated){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            //redirect back to students page
            console.log(newlyCreated);
             res.redirect("/students");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So, Is there any error coming in?

Comment: Only the data from the second part of the form get printed on the final route.

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow this approach, however, if you have really big form. I advise you to create Modals for every step. Also, recommend you to create separate controller for forms. This is how you can achieve for the above form:

```
// I am assuming that you will show first form and then second form as there is no validation added
var formData = {name: name,preference: preference}; // when you have big forms create model for it

//step will make your route dynamic

router.post("/students/:step",middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
    // get data from form and add to students array

    if (req.params.step == 1) { 
       formData.name = req.body.name;
       return '' //do nothing as you should submit form in next step
    }
    else { 
       
       formData.preference = req.body.preference;     
       Student.create(formData, function(err, newlyCreated){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            //redirect back to students page
            console.log(newlyCreated);
           //  res.redirect("/students"); // you don't need to redirect
             formData = {name:'' ,preference: ''};
             res.status(201).send({message: 'New User Created'});
        }
    });
    }
    
});
```

In your HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 style="text-align: center">Register Yourself</h1>
        <div style="width: 30%; margin: 25px auto;">
            <form action="/students/1" method="POST"> //add id for every step
                 <label for="preference">Choose a catagory:</label>
                    <select name="preference" class="form-control">
                     <option value="Male">Male</option>
                      <option value="Female">Female</option>
                      <option value="Any">Any</option>
                     </select>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ">Submit!</button>
                </div>
                </form>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 style="text-align: center">Register Yourself</h1>
        <div style="width: 30%; margin: 25px auto;">
            <form action="/students/2" method="POST"> //add id for every step
                 <label for="preference">Choose a catagory:</label>
                    <select name="preference" class="form-control">
                     <option value="Male">Male</option>
                      <option value="Female">Female</option>
                      <option value="Any">Any</option>
                     </select>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary ">Submit!</button>
                </div>
                </form>
                
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At this moment, I can think of this approach.